# Are 'him' and 'as' redundant in this sentence? What should be the correct construction?

Tags: pronouns, whom

Construction 1: "John Lenon, whom the fans call him their savior,..."

Construction 2: "John Lenon, whom the fans call as their savior,..."

Construction 3: "John Lenon, whom the fans call their savior,..."

Comment: The first 2 constructions sound ungrammatical. The third sentence is correct.

Comment: The second construction sounds indeed wrong to my ears. The third construction should be correct. The first construction should be correct as well, even though the 'him' might be considered redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third sentence is correct. No. 1 doesn't need 'him' - it's already indicated within 'whom'. No.2 is just plain wrong!